# AngularJS1.5 injector issue (MacOSX)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector, angularjs-1.5

Hey all I'm getting this [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzY5Q.png) when trying to use 'gulp serve-dev' on my codebase (https://github.com/CraigOldfield/AngularJSWork). The steps to reproduce where as follows:

1. Clone the repo onto my machine (this machine already had node
   installed and gulp (globally).
2. Run npm install and bower install
3. Run gulp serve-dev form the root directory
4. Previous command opened a browser and the console is reporting the injector issue, this very same code worked this morning on my work (windows) computer, I am now on my home (Mac) computer.

Im very new to Mac so it could be something related to that, I'm hoping someone can give me some more information to help debug this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a version dependency.  I'd suspect that the Mac is using a different version of some package which has different or additional dependencies vs. the Windows system.

Comment: I used bower file and npm to install the packages and those specify versions so I would assume they are the same between the two? Is there any way to narrow down which might be the suspect package?

Comment: You should keep your versions of angular and angular-animate in sync. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768153/3980911

Comment: Hey @yadejo, please post an answer to this question so I can accept it, in the meantime I have created an answer to sit in place. Thanks so much for your help worked perfect.

Comment: If a comment helped you to answer your own question, you can perfectly create an answer yourself and accept it. Welcome to SO btw ;)

Comment: Yes I did that earlier, just wanted to give credit to the correct person :P thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking at this question with the same problem, what worked for me is the following comment by Yadejo.

Yadejo's comment "You should keep your versions of angular and angular-animate in sync. Take a look here: stackoverflow.com/a/32768153/3980911"

Once I updated my bower.json file to have the same version for each of these dependancies, I ran 'npm install' and 'bower install' which fixed the issues I described in the question above.